# React accessing childeren elements inside tag

Tags: reactjs, components

I was asked to change to following style:

```
      <More>
        {Dates}
        {Info}
        {articles}
      </More>
```

But how do i now access these inside More component? before, i passed them as props for More, but now all i have is code example saying {childeren}, nothing else..

More component:

```
 <div>
  {isOpen ? {?!?} : null}
  <Button
    onClick={toggleShowMore}
    text={showMoreButtonText}
    variation={'tertiary'}
    iconPosition={'iconRight'}
    Icon={isOpen ? chevronUp : chevronDown}
  />
</div>
```

EDIT: So objective here would be to show/hide content of More (Dates, Info...) based on isOpen boolean.

Comment: Could you please share the current working code in Code Sandbox? So that we can understand what is happening now.

Comment: @SelvaS i dont have a working code for this. Nothing is happening right now, since i have no idea how to hide/show the components inside More based on isOpen toggle.

Comment: Try to put the content inside the condition `{isOpen ? {<><Button>Test</Button></>} : null}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, the title of your question itself tell you what to do - use `children`:

```
const More = ({ children }) => {

   return (
     <div>
      {isOpen ? children : null}
      ...
     </div>
   );

}
```

Is this what you want?